# Find a word or string using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have been trying to check if a word contains in a webpage. In a nutshell, I tried using:

```
invoke-WebRequest https://example.com | select-string "some text"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Invoke-WebRequest` returns more than just the content of the web page (e.g. headers, response code, etc). You need to use the `Content` property from the response to get to the content of the web page:

```
if ((Invoke-WebRequest "https://example.com").Content | Select-String "some text") {
    Write-Host "I found the text."
}
```